# A Repository Factory Class

Tags: c#, repository

```
public enum RepositoryType
{
    ClinicRepository,
    MedicationRepository,
    PatientRepository,
    TreatmentRepository
}

public class ObjectFactory<T>
{
    public static IRepository<T> GetRepositoryInstance(RepositoryType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case RepositoryType.ClinicRepository:
                return new what ?;

            default:
                return what ?
        }
    }
}

public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T item);
    void Remove(int id);
    void Update(T item);
    IList<T> GetAll();
    T GetItemById(int id);
}
```

I'm trying to create a RepositoryFactory class and I copied what I've done so far. Could anyone please help me to figure this out ? I'm stuck !
Thanks in advance

edit :

I want something like this at the end. Is it possible to make 1 Repository class and implement something like

dc.THATOBJECT.insertonsubmit(item) ?

```
public class TreatmentRepository : IRepository<Treatment>
{
    public void Add(Treatment item)
    {
        using (PatientsDataContext dc = new PatientsDataContext())
        {
            dc.Treatments.InsertOnSubmit(item);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest of factories just requires that your types derived from IRepository have parameterless constructors.

```
public class ObjectFactory {
    public static TRepository GetRepositoryInstance<T, TRepository>() 
      where TRepository : IRepository<T>, new() {
        return new TRepository();
    }
}
```

If you require specific constructors for a given repository type, you can specify the objects as an object array and create them using `CreateInstance`

```
public class ObjectFactory {
    public static TRepository GetRepositoryInstance<T, TRepository>(
      params object[] args) 
      where TRepository : IRepository<T> {
        return (TRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TRepository), args);
    }
}
```

To use either of these, you just need to say

```
var treatmentRepo = 
    ObjectFactory.GetRepositoryInstance<Treatment, TreatmentRepository>();
```

Comment: What is the advantages of using a repository factory?

Answer (score 6):

To have something to return, you need to write a class that implements `IRepository<T>`.

```
public class SomeKindOfRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public void Add(T item)
    {
    }

    // and so on...
}
```

It appears there are four broad types (ClinicRepository, MedicationRepository, etc.) - are they very different in how they "store" things? If so, make a separate class for each one. Otherwise use the same class with some fields to control its behaviour.

**Update**

Based on your edits and comments, you have a repository that is really some operations on a table. The only thing that really varies is which table it wraps around. But the table is a member of a data context. So you could defer the choice of table to a derived class.

This would be the base class:

```
public class GeneralRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    protected abstract Table<TEntity> GetTable(TContext dc);

    public void Add(Treatment item)
    {
        using (TContext dc = new TContext())
        {
            GetTable(dc).InsertOnSubmit(item);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }

    // and so on for other methods
}
```

A derived class would only have to specify how to select a table from the context:

```
public class TreatmentsRepository : GeneralRepository<Treatment, PatientsDataContext>
{
    protected override Table<Treatment> GetTable(PatientsDataContext dc)
    {
        return dc.Treatments;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edit the question. I'm having a linqtosql data context. Is it doable ?

Comment: @Kubi - based on the answer you accepted, I must say have no idea what your question actually was! You asked in your edit about achieving "dc.THATOBJECT.insertonsubmit(item)" That's what my update deals with.

Comment: Your answer was the exact answer for my question but the accepted answer solves my problem as well. I wish I could choose 2 answers as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do without the `enum`. You either need a generic repository type, or different repository types implementing `IRepository<T>`. If you use a generic repository, you can implement the factory by doing something along the lines of:

```
public class ObjectFactory<T>
{
    public static IRepository<T> GetRepositoryInstance()
    {
        return new Repository<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use an Inversion of Control (IoC) container for this. In the Factory (or you could even go straight to the IoC container), could get the type.

```
public interface IClinicRepository : IRepository<Clinic> {}


public class ObjectFactory
{
   public static IRepository<T> GetRepository(RepositoryType type)
   { 
     switch (type)
     {
         case RepositoryType.ClinicRepository:
             return container.Resolve<IClinicRepository>()
          default:
             throw new NotSupportedException()
     } 
   }
}
```

or better yet Just use a generic method in your factory

```
   public static IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>()
   { 
       return container.Resolve<T>()
   }


   // to call it
   var repository = ObjectFactory.GetRepository<IClinicRepository>();
```